# PHALCON PHP - Different views based on user profile

Tags: php, model-view-controller, phalcon

I created Phalcon PHP app,
I have 3 different user profiles: (ID: 1) Administrators, (ID: 2) Accountants and (ID: 3) Warehouses.

I want my app able to render views based on those profiles, for example

```
controllerName/index.1.volt //for Administrators
controllerName/index.2.volt //for Accountants
controllerName/index.3.volt //for Warehouses
```

but when those files weren't found, my app will fallback to:

```
controllerName/index.volt
```

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach, although messy, would be to use `controlerName/index.volt` as the "landing page" then from there check an if-statement to decide what the user's role is. Then from the if-statement use a partial like `{{ partial("index.1.volt") }}` but you'd need to hard-code this for every controller... yuck...

A good solution which I'd recommend, though, would be to make use of the View's [exists](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html) method to check if the view exists from within your controller. The idea is you pass this method the string path to the view file you're looking for but omitting the extension. The reason you omit the extension is because Phalcon allows you to use multiple rendering engines so an application using a mixture of `.volt` and `.phtml` would work.

Assuming you were using user roles something like this:

```
define('GUEST_ROLE',0);
define('ADMIN_ROLE',1);
define('ACCOUNTANT_ROLE',2);
define('WAREHOUSE_ROLE',3);
```

(with the guest role with a value of 0) I would suggest having all your controllers extend a [ControllerBase](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/controllers.html#creating-a-base-controller) then define the following two methods in your ControllerBase:

```
public function getUserLevel()
{
    if($this->session->has('userLevel'))
    {
        $userLevel=$this->session->get('userLevel');
        return (int)$userLevel;
    }else{
        return 0;//default to guest
    }
}

protected function initialize()
{
    $controllerName=$this->dispatcher->getControllerName();
    $actionName=$this->dispatcher->getActionName();
    $userLevel=$this->getUserLevel();
    if($this->view->exists("$controllerName/$actionName.$userLevel"))
    {
        $this->view->pick("$controllerName/$actionName.$userLevel");
    }
    //No reason to add an else, Phalcon defaults to "$controllerName/$actionName"

}
```

Just make sure, that if you ever need to define a custom "initialize" method for a specific controller which extends the ControllerBase, e.g. to add a title prefix to all pages related to the controller, that you call `parent::initialize();` otherwise it won't get called. But that's only if you're going to be overriding the method.

Chances are you're already using a ControllerBase and doing similar logic already, if so, you'd need to edit your already existing "initialize" method and merge my code with yours.

Happy coding.